# is "I have x years of experience in ABC shop" equal to "I have x years of experience in a particular job in ABC shop"?

Tags: sentence-choice

I am a shop assistant in ABC shop. I have been working there for several years.

Given that situation, when I want to tell people about my work experience,

Is it alright to use the shorter sentence 1 instead of sentence 2 in a conversation?
Will people understand what I mean?

Sentence 1:

> I have several years of experience in ABC shop.

Sentence 2:

> I have several years of experience as a shop assistant in ABC shop.

Comment: Both are OK. #2 gives more info. However, if "ABC" is the *name* of the shop, then it isn't idiomatic.  "**at** ABC", e.g. "at Brenda's High-Style Hat Shop" or "in a hat shop".

Comment: Than you for your help, Tᴚoɯɐuo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are *informally* chatting with friends then the shorter form

> I have several years of experience **at** ABC.
>   I have worked for several years **at** ABC.

may be fine, but if you are looking for a job, the longer form

> I have several years of experience *as a shop assistant* **at ABC**.

would be better since is explains what your years of experience was.